# how make [Object object] to string in react

Tags: reactjs, prop

**Question:**
export function Main () {

```
return (
  <div className="py-4">
  <Discount/>
  <Text
  subtitle={`
  ${JSON.stringify(`${<h1>Some <p className="class">generation</p> here</h1>}` )}
  `}/>
  </div>
)
}
```

I want output text as in image (when some text ***have class***)
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgylM.png)

I use react js
**MVP**:https://codesandbox.io/s/props-modificator-7nt43o?file=/src/App.js
`JSON.parse` doesn't helps
`JSON.stringify` doesn't helps

**There are 3 solutions**

```
 export function Main () {
  
  const subtitleHtml = `Some <p class='text-gradient'>solution2</p> here`;


return (
  <div className="py-4">
  <Discount/>
  <Text

  title={<div className="flex flex-row gap-1.5">Some<p class='text-gradient'>solution1</p> here</div>}

subtitle={<div className="flex flex-row gap-1" 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: subtitleHtml }} />}

//I find this the best one cause you can wrap {solution3} in any <tag>
solution3={
          <h1 class="text-7xl font-bold">
            The Next
            <span class="text-gradient"> solution 3 </span>
            Payment method.
          </h1>
        }
      />
      </div>
    )
    }
```

**Solutions MVP** - https://codesandbox.io/s/props-modificator-forked-dnxmnu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take a JSX object

```
<h1>Some <p className="class">generation</p> here</h1>
```

and stringify it

```
`${<h1>Some <p className="class">generation</p> here</h1>}`
```

that's where you get your `[object Object]` string.

Then you `JSON.stringify('[object Object]')` which gives you another string: `'"[object Object]"'`.

Then you take this string and wrap it into yet another string:

```
subtitle={`
  ${'"[object Object]"'}
  `}
```

ain't that a bit overkill?

If you want to pass the `<h1>...</h1>` to the `<Text />` then just do so:

```
return (
  <div className="py-4">
    <Discount/>
    <Text subtitle={<h1>Some <p className="class">generation</p> here</h1>} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: It returns an error https://prnt.sc/MV8V2eZPg6LC

Comment: @Nevazno_html_css_js_3 The error message makes no sense and images are hard to debug. https://codesandbox.io/s/props-modificator-forked-r434u7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes thank you I find this solution better

Answer (score 0):

You're approach of converting HTML string to JSON is incorrect and will result in a JSON string that represents a string containing HTML markup rather than the HTML itself. Try this:

```
function App() {
  const subtitleHtml = "<h1>Some <p className='class'>text</p> here</h1>";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Text subtitle={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: subtitleHtml }} />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute accepts an object with an __html property whose value is set to the HTML string.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/props-modificator-forked-3n6n1j?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

Comment: It works - you just need add `class=` instead `className=` in const subtitleHtml - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
export function Main () {
  
  const subtitleHtml = `Some <p class='text-gradient'>solution2</p> here`;


return (
  <div className="py-4">
  <Discount/>
  <Text

  title={<div className="flex flex-row gap-1.5">Some<p class='text-gradient'>solution1</p> here</div>}

subtitle={<div className="flex flex-row gap-1" 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: subtitleHtml }} />}

//I find this the best one cause you can wrap {solution3} in any <tag>
solution3={
          <h1 class="text-7xl font-bold">
            The Next
            <span class="text-gradient"> solution 3 </span>
            Payment method.
          </h1>
        }
      />
      </div>
    )
    }
```

MVP:https://codesandbox.io/s/props-modificator-forked-dnxmnu?file=/src/App.js:256-272

Thanks:
[Bob Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10966512/bob-junior)
[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas)